# Why aren't folder sizes shown in File Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

Is it possible to turn it on? If so, how?

I found [this](https://www.4winkey.com/windows-10/how-to-show-view-folder-size-in-windows-10.html#1) and I tried the method in part 1, but it still doesn't work (actually, it wasn't even unchecked in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to turn it on.

The easiest way to view folder size is to just hover your mouse over the folder, or go to folder Properties.

If you want it to be displayed in list view, you will have to download other software like TreeSize.

Comment: +1 for TreeSize Free edition. It's one of the tools in my arsenal.